# RuntimeError: Error compiling objects for extension while installing detectron2

Tags: compiler-errors, pytorch, runtime-error, miniconda, detectron

I’m trying to install detectron2 on my local machine. A cpp_extension.py located in

> C:\Users\Username\miniconda3\envs\pytorch_env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py

fails to compile and throws a

> raise RuntimeError(message) from e
> RuntimeError: Error compiling objects for extension

I just finished installing the tensorflow object detection API so I have pycocotools and other c++ build tools required. Are there more extensions of c++ tools I would have to install?

- OS: windows 10, no GPU
- Visual Studio tools installed: 2015 and 2019 build tools, windows 10 sdk, windows universal crt and crt sdk
- pytorch version: 1.12.1

command leading to error:

```
python -m pip install -e detectron2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look into this raised GitHub issue:

> https://github.com/facebookresearch/maskrcnn-benchmark/issues/1236

It most likely is a Pytorch version(compatibility) problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try PyTorch ≥ 1.6 and <1.9.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error which i was able to solve after spending 1 whole day.

The below mentioned are my configurations in ubuntu machine:

> Python version: 3.11.0rc1 
> Torch version: 2.1.0+cu118 
> TorchVision version: 0.16.0+cu118 
> TorchAudio version: 2.1.0+cu118 
> Detectron2 version: 0.6

And I installed detectron2 by running the following command:

`pip install -e git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git@864913f0e57e87a75c8cc0c7d79ecbd774fc669b#egg=detectron2`

For me the file

> C:\Users\Username\miniconda3\envs\pytorch_env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py

was failing to compile and throwing this error as well

> raise RuntimeError(message) from e RuntimeError: Error compiling
> objects for extension

I solved it by running this command

`sudo apt-get install python3.11-dev`

Make sure gcc & g++ are correctly setup